# Spring boot/cloud microservices on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, microservices, netflix

I have created a Spring cloud microservices based application with netflix APIs (Eureka, config, zuul etc). can some one explain me how to deploy that on AWS? I am very new to AWS. I have to deploy development instance of my application.

Do I need to integrate docker before that or I can go ahead without docker as well.

Comment: All the services with (10 jars) - including spring boot microservices (7 services),  eureka registry, zuul and config service are working fine on windows server. 
I am able to run the application. 
how to deploy it on AWS and what changes it requires on configuration/or any other in my current application before deploy.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your application is self-contained and you have externalised your configurations, you should not have any issue.

Go through this link which discusses what it takes to deploy an App to Cloud [Beyond 15 factor](https://content.pivotal.io/ebooks/beyond-the-12-factor-app)

Use AWS BeanStalk to deploy and Manage your application. Dockerizing your app is not a predicament inorder to deploy your app to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an EC2 instance then it's configuration is no different to what you do on your local machine/server. It's just a virtual machine. No need to dockerize or anything like that. And if you're new to AWS, I'd rather suggest to to just that. Once you get your head around, you can explore other options.

For example, AWS Beanstalk seems like a popular option. It provides a very secure and reliable configuration out of the box with no effort on your part. And yes, it does use docker under the hood, but you won't need to deal with it directly unless you choose to. Well, at least in most common cases. It supports few different ways of deployment which amazon calls "Application Environments". See [here](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/getting-started/) for details. Just choose the one you like and follow instructions. I'd like to warn you though that whilst Beanstalk is usually easier then EC2 to setup and use when dealing with a typical web application, your mileage might vary depending on your application's actual needs.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Elastic container Service / Elastic Kubernetes Service is also a good option to look into.

These services depend on the Docker Images of your application. Auto Scaling, Availability cross region replication will be taken care by the Cloud provider.

Hope this helps.